Seek solutions to issues related to homosexuality
I think I was born gay.I am only seventeen years old.I had a great time with my  boyfriend. Now I'm weak to him. I am a Muslim, I pray and fast But I can't get this haram relationship out of my mind, I feel sexually oriented again and again. For many reasons I can't get out of wanting to bring myself to the path of Islam that I love someone who is of my gender. I feel attracted to him. I want to solve this. And it is better to say something about how I will return to the path of Islam.

Welcome to Islam SE. The site is not for personal advice. Please read: https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . I pray that Allah helps you, Aameen.

No one is born gay in Islam.
Don’t ascribe evil to Allah. That’s a evil thought and a sin in itself.
Allah made everyone pure of no sin.
He wouldn’t make a baby who is sinful
“So direct your face toward the religion, inclining to truth. [Adhere to] the fitrah of Allah upon which He has created [all] people. No change should there be in the creation of Allah . That is the correct religion, but most of the people do not know.” - Quran 30:30
“What comes to you of good is from Allah , but what comes to you of evil, [O man], is from yourself”- Quran 4:79

Read the site rules, please. Avoid answering questions that are off-topic or looking for personal advice and point them to the right way. Secondly, there are people born with certain deficiencies and some people born even with additional chromosomes or lacking chromosomes. Don't project your ideals of "evil" to Allah SWT. There is no doubt that homosexual behavior is haram in Islam and a major sin but the statement that no one can have it without any evildoing of their own is not true. One can have it due to factors not under their control.

There are, in fact, even multiple psychological problems like certain forms of psychopathy that people have since birth or childhood. They are born to not feel certain emotions. Their brain simply lacks the ability to send the right signals to release the chemicals for them so they are inherently insensitive to a lot of things we deem "evil". However, it still does not convey that Allah made them evil in any way the same way that someone with same-sex attraction of any form without any doing of their own is made evil. The sinfulness is acting upon such, not in growing up with it.

Please read: https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

As for the verses you have quoted, they have very little to do with the question unless they are interpreted the exact way you want them to be interpreted.

Deficiency isn’t a sin and those verses are very relevant

That is exactly what I am saying. If somebody is born with something that inherently leads to evil, it doesn't mean that they are born with evil itself. If someone is grows up to find themselves gay, they are not sinful. They are only sinful if they act upon their gay feelings. Their only option is to have sabr and fast or seek therapy.

Moreover, please explain why those verses are relevant. You cannot claim something without giving a proof for it. This site is not to share your opinions but to give almost academic-quality answers with generally accepted references. What you think or interpret of the verse is irrelevant. What's relevant is an excerpt from a tafsir or from a fatwa or something else from a scholar or a hadith clearly mentioning what you are claiming.

Being born blind deaf or one leg isn’t evil yet being born gay is an Evil and Quran says no evil can be attributed to Allah

As I said, it is not evil. Evil is acting on one's homosexual desires and doing intercourse with someone of the same gender or watching pornography, or another action of that sort. Having a desire, in and of itself is not evil. It is similar to how heterosexual desires are in and of themselves not evil and only acting upon them outside of marriage is evil. Someone may be born with such a brain and grow up to realize they have such desires, similar to how someone may be born with a form of psychopathy.

Secondly, you are interpreting the verse by yourself. Give me actual reliable tafsir. Allah was the one who allowed the action of Adam alayhissalam eating the fruit. That is, in someone's limited perspective, "evil". Allah was the one who allowed Iblis to go astray, that too, in someone's limited perspective be evil. The humans and jinns have free will but their actions are only allowed by Allah SWT. Not even a leaf falls from a tree except that Allah allows it to.

Allah didn’t make him eat the apple Allah doesn’t make anyone do evil read the verse it’s clear Allah doesn’t make people do evil

You do not know the difference between making someone do something and allowing it. You don't have basic knowledge of theology and you blabber nonsense about things you have no idea about and refuse to provide references for them, no tafsir, no nothing. It's a major sin in Islam to talk about something without having complete knowledge of it. Please follow the site rules mentioned here at: https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer and provide accepted, academic references for your things and always avoid your own interpretations of any of the texts.

I won't proceed in this conversation with you anymore. May Allah guide you, Aameen.
